How single-tap equalization can be performed in OFDM for perfect channel estimation?
If I have for example IFFT length of 3 with cyclic prefix length of 2 and 3 channel taps, how can I illustrate the frequency domain equalization in OFDM?
For example as far as I know, it's elementwise multiplication of frequency responses, as there is a circular convolution in time domain for ofdm. Thus, for the above example, if x={x1,x2,x3} and channel impulse response is h={h1,h2}. So, for equalization how can I show the illustration to get back the original transmitted sequence by removing the effect of channel tap coefficients?

Hello and welcome, your question does not seem to be programming related, but rather theoretical signal processing. It would be better to ask this question at dsp.stackexchange
